# How to set two triggers correct?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with game stats for users. In there is filed ENERGY and field IS_ALIVE. When users reach energy <= 0 trigger makes update and set IS_ALIVE on FALSE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_users_stats_insup_bef()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF NEW.energy <= 0 THEN
   NEW.is_alive := FALSE;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF energy ON users_stats
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_users_stats_insup_bef();
```

Second trigger if update IS_ALIVE on FALSE should make update on table with stats how much is dead and alive users yet?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_update_users_stats_insup_aft()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
UPDATE game_statistics 
    SET 
        total_users = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_stats), 
        dead_users = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_stats WHERE is_alive = FALSE), 
        alive_users = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_stats WHERE is_alive = TRUE);
RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insup_aft
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF is_alive ON users_stats  -- covers INSERT, too
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_update_users_stats_insup_aft();
```

If i make UPDATE users_stats SET is_alive = FALSE so trigger makes update on table with statistics users who is alive and who not so this is work trigger no 2. but if i make UPDATE uses_stats SET energy = -2 so trigger only change is_alive on FALSE (work trigger no 1) but not make update on statistics_dead_alive_users. Does anyone can know what i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Because changes made to the row's contents by BEFORE UPDATE triggers are not considered as to trigger the after update trigger...

Comment: So in first trigger if energy <=0 i should run procedure or function from second trigger ?

Comment: that would be a solution, yes